# Beamer: displaying four images, how to pre-allocate space for the first image?

Tags: beamer, spacing, graphics, includegraphics

I am trying to display four images in the following order:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, since the second image hasn't appeared after displaying the first one, therefore the **first image is slightly downward as compared to its final location**.

How can I fix this issue, i.e., pre-allocate enough space so the first image is at the location where it is supposed to be?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}{\raggedright\insertcaption\par}
\def\Put(#1,#2)#3{\leavevmode\makebox(0,0){\put(#1,#2){#3}}}
\newcommand{\xsub}[1]{%
  \mbox{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \frame{\titlepage}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Birds}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
%centering
\hspace*{-0.3cm}                                              
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.3cm]{bird1.jpg}\\
\only<2->{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.5cm]{bird2.jpg}}
\column{.5\textwidth}
%\centering
\only<3->{\hspace*{-0.3cm}                                            
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.3cm]{bird3.jpg}}\\
\only<4->{\hspace*{-0.3cm}                                             
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.5cm]{bird4.jpg}}
\end{columns}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` with beamer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, give an ECM. I have removed all that is unnecessary to understand and reproduce the problem.

To solve the problem, just use the `\visible` command instead of `\only`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Birds}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}                                
\visible<1->{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.3cm]{bird1.jpg}}
\visible<2->{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.5cm]{bird2.jpg}}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\visible<3->{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.3cm]{bird3.jpg}}
\visible<4->{\hspace*{-0.3cm} \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3.5cm]{bird4.jpg}}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```